# Is this enough support for my countertop?

Tags: kitchens

I am putting a new countertop in (Lustrastone, is like Durastone) that will wrap around an outcorner wall.  Along one side is a 48" wide base cabinet and the countertop will be 38" deep.  It will extend 18" beyond the left side of the base cabinet and wrap around an outcorner wall that is not as strong as a regular wall because it has a pocket door in it. That part of the countertop will run 40" along the wall and will be 18" deep. The full length of that will actually be the 40" along the wall + the 38" deep.  I am planning to use hidden countertop support along the front of the base cabinet.  I am trying to figure out how to support the countertop along the wall and side of the base cabinet without depending on the wall to bear the weight.  I would like to stay away from a leg support on the outer corner of the countertop.  I am thinking about using hammered steel tubing that is 2" X 1".  Here is what I have in mind:

Run the tubing horizontally along the wall (the cabinet does not reach the corner....it is about 1 1/2" from the corner....... I will have to run the tubing along the side of the cabinet also)

Place a piece of tubing against the wall from the floor to the bottom of the horizontal tubing, acting as a leg, where each cast iron or wrought iron corbel will be

### Attach the corbels to the horizontal tubing and vertical tubing (the corbels will not necessarily be where there are studs in the wall)

The countertop will sit on 1" tubing as it will be placed flat on the wall.  I am not sure how deep or high the corbels need to be.  The Lustrastone will be formed with plywood under it.

Will my idea work?  Will the tubing be strong enough?

Comment: Some photos or sketches might help folks visualize the situation better.

Comment: Would like to help, but it really would take me too much time to try to visualize what you are going to do. Agree with @Tester101.

Answer (score 2):

We specialize in Countertop Supports. Using Hidden Brackets on the front base of your cabinet will be fine with an 18" overhang. We recommend you have no more than 4" unsupported countertop out beyond the extension of the bracket, meaning using a 14" plate/bracket would be sufficient. Also recommended is installing a plate/bracket at each end of the countertop within 4" from the edge, then spacing the additional brackets evenly between those two, 18" apart. I figure you would need 4 brackets.

For the 40" long, 38" deep countertop, I understand one side of this is connected to the countertop on top of a base cabinet. Are both ends of the 40"W/38"D countertop supported by base cabinets? If so, you can also use Hidden Brackets here as well. You would attach to the side of the cabinet base extending under the unsupported countertop. With the unsupported size of 40"x38", mounting to the sides of the cabinet bases, you can use 18" plates or 18" x 18" L Brackets. You would need to install 2 on each side of the cabinet base for a total of 4. You would place each 2 brackets within 4" from the edge of the countertop. This unsupported area would now be fully supported.

If I have misunderstood your design, I apologize. If you could attach a sketch of your design, I will be happy to assist.